# I need a time selector in my template of angular material which gives the time in the format hh:mm:ss in ng-model only not along with the date

Tags: javascript, django, angular-material, momentjs

this is the template code of timepicker I am using currently but it doesnt give the desired output

```
<md-input-container flex-gt-sm class="md-block">
        <label>Opening Time</label>
        <md-icon md-svg-src="/cityaplfreelisting/media/time.svg" class="mdicon"></md-icon>
        <input required  mdc-datetime-picker date="false" time="true" type="text" short-time="true"
               show-todays-date click-outside-to-close="true"
               auto-ok="true"
               min-date="minDate" minute-steps="1"
               format="hh:mm a"
               ng-change="vm.saveChange()"
               ng-model="opening.time">
     </md-input-container>                    
    <md-input-container flex-gt-sm class="md-block">
        <label>Closing Time</label>
        <md-icon md-svg-src=" /cityaplfreelisting/media/time.svg" class="mdicon"></md-icon>
        <input required  mdc-datetime-picker date="false" time="true" type="text" short-time="true"
               show-todays-date click-outside-to-close="true"
               auto-ok="true"
               min-date="minDate" minute-steps="1"
               format="hh:mm a"
               ng-change="vm.saveChange()"
               ng-model="closing.time">
     </md-input-container>
```

this is code of django model

```
from django.db import models

class Shop(models.Model):
    openingTime = models.TimeField()
    closingTime = models.TimeField()
```

I used a timepicker of moment.js but it gives time along with the date. which my data base is not accepting. I am using django in my backend and sending data through a REST API.
[Moment js time picker is giving the output in the form of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMjYk.png)

But I need time only not date

Comment: <input id="time" type="time"> https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/input.time.html

Comment: still not working